# Is there any way to get the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of a block of code in Java rather than of the entire class ?

Tags: java, python, abstract-syntax-tree

I tried using Javalang module available in python to get the AST of Java source code , but it requires an entire class to generate the AST . Passing a block of code like an 'if' statement throws an error . Is there any other way of doing it ?
PS : I am preferably looking for a python module to do the task.
Thanks

Comment: "but it requires an entire class to generate the AST " I thought this is to be expected as Java itself requires that every piece of code to be inside a class?

Comment: More specifically I want to compare in two code snippets whether one is just a refactoring of other or there is some logical change ? So i though of comparing their ASTs

Comment: If you don't insist on a Python solution, I have a practical answer.

Comment: Sure , please share

Answer (score 2):

[Javalang](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang) can parse snippets of Java code:

```
>>> tokens = javalang.tokenizer.tokenize('System.out.println("Hello " + "world");')
>>> parser = javalang.parser.Parser(tokens)
>>> parser.parse_expression()
MethodInvocation
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is interested in a non-Python answer.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html?) can accomplish this.

DMS is a general purpose tools for parsing/analyzing/transforming code, parameterized by langauge definitions (including grammars).  Given a langauge definition, DMS can easily be invoked on a source file/stream representing the goal symbol for a grammar by calling the Parse method offered by the langauge parameter, and DMS will build a tree for the parsed string.   Special support is provided for parsing source file/streams for arbitrary nonterminals as defined by the langauge grammar; DMS will build an AST whose root is that nonterminal, parsing the source according to the subgrammar define by that nonterminal.

Once you have the AST, DMS provides lots of support for visiting the AST, inspecting/modifying nodes, carry out source-to-source transformations on the AST using surface syntax rewrite rules.  Finally you can prettyprint the modified AST and get back valid source code.  (If you have only parsed a code fragment for a nonterminal, what you get back is valid code for that nonterminal).

If OP is willing to compare complete files instead of snippets, our Smart Differencer might be useful out of the box.  SmartDifferencer builds ASTs of its two input files, finds the smallest set of conceptual edits (insert, delete, move, copy, rename) over structured code elemnts that explains the differences, and reports that difference.